# AuthenticationException error while adding data to Google Sheet using Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-sheets-api

I am trying to add data to Google Sheet using Java. To do this I am following this [article](https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/interacting-with-google-spreadsheet-with-java/).
Here is my code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SheetService {
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("spreadsheetservice");

    public String setUserCredentials(String username, String password) {
        try {
            service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
            return "Credentials set.";
        } catch (AuthenticationException authenticationException) {
            authenticationException.printStackTrace();
            return "Error";
        }
    }

    private static final String SPREADSHEET_SERVICE_URL  = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full";


    public SpreadsheetEntry getSpreadsheet(String sheetName) {
        try {
            URL spreadSheetFeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_SERVICE_URL);

            SpreadsheetQuery spreadsheetQuery = new SpreadsheetQuery(
                    spreadSheetFeedUrl);
            spreadsheetQuery.setTitleQuery(sheetName);
            spreadsheetQuery.setTitleExact(true);
            SpreadsheetFeed spreadsheet = service.getFeed(spreadsheetQuery,
                    SpreadsheetFeed.class);

            if (spreadsheet.getEntries() != null
                    && spreadsheet.getEntries().size() == 1) {
                return spreadsheet.getEntries().get(0);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }

        return null;
    }

    public WorksheetEntry getWorkSheet(String sheetName, String workSheetName) {
        try {
            SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = getSpreadsheet(sheetName);

            if (spreadsheet != null) {
                WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
                        spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
                List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();

                for (WorksheetEntry worksheetEntry : worksheets) {
                    String wktName = worksheetEntry.getTitle().getPlainText();
                    if (wktName.equals(workSheetName)) {
                        return worksheetEntry;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }

        return null;
    }

    public ListEntry createRow(Map<String, String> rowValues) {
        ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
        for (String columnName : rowValues.keySet()) {
            String value = rowValues.get(columnName);
            row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal(columnName, value);
        }
        return row;
    }

    String username = "******@gmail.com";
    String password = "*******";
    String sheetName = "*******";
    String workSheetName = "Sheet1";
    String res = setUserCredentials(username, password);
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = getWorkSheet(sheetName, workSheetName);
    URL listFeedUrl = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
    Map<String,String> rowValues = new HashMap<>();
    public SheetService() throws IOException, ServiceException {
        rowValues.put("name", "Nikhil");
    }


    ListEntry row = createRow(rowValues);
    ListEntry addedRow = service.insert(listFeedUrl, row);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SheetService.class, args);
    }
}
```

While I try to run this, I keep getting the error `com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)`.

Can anyone please help.
Also if someone knows another easier way to populate data into a Google sheet, I'll be grateful to know that. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The article you referenced is using Google Data API. This is an older API. If you want to interact with Sheets via API, please consider using [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api). Take a look at the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). Does that answer your question?

Comment: I was trying to use Sheets API but ran into errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968633/writing-data-to-google-sheets-using-java

Comment: Well, I don't think moving to the older API is a solution. Please consider providing whatever code you are using for Sheets API in order to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I was following this article https://www.baeldung.com/google-sheets-java-client to use Sheets API. The problem is that it keeps asking to allow permission everytime some data needs to be inserted into the sheet. I need to find a way to bypass that.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and you have to use a service account for that. I assume you are not working on any code that? You can start by checking the links provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66969698), specially [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

Comment: Hi, I went through the articles, but I am facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66968633/writing-data-to-google-sheets-using-java . Could you please help, I'll be really grateful.